# nginx too many redirects HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: nginx, https, redirect, http, raspbian

I have a problem with accessing my site from Internet.

When I am trying to do that the browser is showing the error "too many redirections" or "redirection loop".

This is my site conf file. I changed my domain name with example.com. My server is running on raspbian on raspberry pi 4B.  I have found other similar questions.  but none of them seem to solve the problem.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;

    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem;
    include snippets/ssl.conf;
    include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;

    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com;

    root /var/www/example.com;

    index index.php;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem;
    include snippets/ssl.conf;
    include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|svg)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

I would be highly grateful if anyone can point out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: when i try to access my site loading is failing because of too many redirections.

Comment: Why do you think it's a problem with http→https redirect, and not a application problem?

Comment: because before i installed ssl and added redirections everything was fine

Comment: if you think problem is different just tell me what i should show and how to fix it

Comment: You should check your application, because it is most likely redirecting you back to http, while nginx is redirecting you to https.

Comment: After a redirection loop you should also restart your browser. Browsers remember `301` redirections, so if you had a loop, but corrected it, the browser will not notice.

Comment: ok but i don't understand what i should to to fix it

Comment: Could you post the nginx logs showing the redirects?

Comment: You have www.example.com to example.com redirection. Try redirection from example.com to www.example.com. also check browser logs (from developers/network tab) to see exactly what is going on.

Comment: You can add the output of `curl -i https://example.com/` and some details on the PHP application running. As mentioned above, the application, not nginx, is probably sending redirects.